# Why is case insensitive search and replace not working in Solaris sed?

Tags: sed, solaris

I tried the following commands in Solaris `sed` for case insensitive find and replace

```
sed s/TOFIND/REPLACE/gi fileName
sed s/TOFIND/REPLACE/gi fileName

/usr/xpg4/bin/sed s/TOFIND/REPLACE/gi fileName
/usr/xpg4/bin/sed s/TOFIND/REPLACE/gi fileName
```

but none of the ways worked. I got command garbled error for all. Is there no support for case insensitive search in Solaris `sed`?

Comment: For some reason, shell scripting is generally not considered a programming language by stackoverflow users. You'd better then ask this kind of question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is a non standard GNU sed extension.

You can use `GNU sed` if installed. It might be in `/usr/sfw/bin/gsed` or `/usr/gnu/bin/sed` depending on the version.

Otherwise, the standard way is

```
sed 's/[Tt][Oo][Ff][Ii][Nn][Dd]/REPLACE/g' fileName
```

You might automatize the process that way:

```
pattern="tofind"
sed "s/$(printf "%s" "$pattern"|sed 's/./\[\U&\L&\]/g')/REPLACE/g" fileName
```

Comment: I think in this line sed 's/[Tt][Oo][Ff][Ii][Nn][Dd]/REPLACE/gi' fileName i in the last should not come.

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks for pointing that error, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative is to replace each aphabetic char of the search pattern by his equivalent `[sC]` like `this:` by `[tT][hH][iI][sS]:` (with a previous sed/awk on pattern to be generic)

```
printf "%s\n" "SearchPattern" | sed 's/[aA]/[aA]/g;s[bB]/[bB]/g; ..... ;s/[zZ]/[zZ]/g' | read -r CaseSearchPattern

/usr/xpg4/bin/sed "s/${CaseSearchPattern}/REPLACE/g" fileName
```

just add a second test eventually (and corrective action) if some special char like \ are in the content due to "" shell interpretation arround the sed action

Comment: I did this frequently enough that I wrote a program to produce a case-insensitive search string given a case-sensitive (literal) string.  Thus: `mkpattern alphabet` produces `[aA][lL][pP][hH][aA][bB][eE][tT]`.